# How to rename / move a project in Intellij Idea 12?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, ide

As stated [here](http://link.sheidaei.com/mozcw) one can change the name of a project. However, it only changes the name of the project and it will not change the folder structure.

As an example if your project is called sample1 and it resides ~/user1/development/IdeaProjects/sample1, the folder location won't be changed to ~/user1/development/IdeaProjects/sample2 if one changes the project name to sample2.

Comment: Why not just rename the folder through windows explorer?

Comment: @redFIVE Does that result in Project name change as well?

Comment: No you can rename your project as in the link you posted. If you need to move/rename the root folder you your project, just do it through explorer, don't need an IDE to do basic windows stuff.

Comment: @redFIVE using Refactoring in Intellij insures to update any dependencies if there are any. Thus, relying on the IDE is highly recommended.

Comment: You project root folder and your project name are unrelated. You can change either without affecting the other. If sample1 is the root folder you want renamed, you can literally just rename the folder in windows explorer to sample2. Your project may have been named the same as your root folder on creation, but one does not depend on the other. It will NOT break dependencies, thats not how it works. If you are talking about changing the internal package structure, then re-edit your question clarify your question more.

Comment: @redFIVE That is utterly false under Linux. If you change the folder name, the IntelliJ IDEA window opened on the project goes blank, and after a short while the original folder gets recreated with the only contents `.idea/workspace.xml`.

Comment: @Urhixidur I only use Linux for development. Also, that comment was from nearly 4 years ago, implementations and linux distros change.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems that one has to right click on the project (after following the instructions to rename the Project), then choose Refactor -> Move to relocate project to the new location. I didn't find any solution to rename and move a project at once.

Comment: It doesn't rename the project folder only moves it. So ultimately you probably have to do that manually

Comment: This doesn't help. It doesn't change of the project folder. Instead of this it creates a new one with a new name and moves there. The old folder of the project folder is inside a new one.

Comment: Works for me in Idea 2017.1, just beware: (1) moving might be slow (I waited for approx. 15m for 471MB project with 16000+ files), (2) for one project, new git root was not detected (but it's easy to correct in Version Control Settings)

Answer (score 47):

1. Right click on project, then *Refactor -> Rename...* (shift+F6), set desired name
2. Close IntelliJ
3. Rename directory in your filesystem to your desired name
4. In startup dialog select *Open* (or *File -> Open*... in main window)
5. Please select renamed project directory

Enjoy, it work's for me!

Comment: The common sense answer. I think we should upvote this. (IJ 2019.3 Community)

Comment: if you wonder - you won't loose any project config this way, because the .idea files will still be there

Answer (score 18):

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Rename the folder in Explorer (Windows) / Finder (OSX)
3. Open IntelliJ
4. Import Project from Dialog, or File -> Import Project
5. Select the folder with the new name
6. Follow the dialogues

Comment: Does not work, all the module settings get reimported with Intellij best guesses

Comment: It works...in a way. I mean this workaround let's you refactor both the IntelliJ metainfo and the folder structure on disk, but it doesn't address anything that probably stays in the main user configuration folder (`~/.IdeaIC2017.3` in my case). So anyone going with this solution is bound to be haunted by some ghost projects in some IntelliJ dialogues later

Answer (score 5):

I know that probably I won't be able to help sheidaei after more than 7 years from asking question, but I hope that someone will find it useful :)
To change project directory name of a current project without closing Intellij, choose **view of "Project Files"** in drop-down menu **in the project browser**(typically on the left) instead of "Project".
[How to select "Project Files" view in project browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owafX.png)
Then use **right-click** on project's **directory name**/path to open context menu.
Use **Refactor->Rename**.
[Finding option "Rename" in context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaD0Q.png)
Type in a new directory name, apply changes using button "Refactor" and that's it.
["Rename" dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWFqP.png)
If you wish to change Module Name to match directory name, use Refactor->Rename option on project name in "Project" view of project browser.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a gradle project, instead of renaming it using *Refactor->Rename* :

- set the `rootProject.name` variable in the *settings.gradle* file to the new project name.
- reimport the project. Hit the 'Refresh all Gradle Projects' button in the Gradle Tool Window.

Then follow steps 2 to 5 in [@Dawid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41563271/3059685).

To remove the old project from IntelliJ's list of managed projects:

- select *File->Open Recent->Manage Projects..*
- click the 'x' next to the old project name

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `File` then `Project Structure`
2. Under `Project Settings -> Project` make sure that you change the project name.
3. Then under `Project Settings -> Modules` change the name there as well.
4. Restart Intellij
5. Use your File Explorer to confirm that the project/modules have been renamed.

Answer (score 2):

After renaming the project folder of a Kotlin project in IntelliJ, using the Import Project option as suggested in the other answers created module related problems for me. I was not able to select Main class in the Run dialogue. To solve this, I used `Create New Project` option. It doesn't delete your project files.

So to rename the folder, first create a copy of your project for safety and then follow these steps:

1. Close IntelliJ.
2. Go to file explorer and manually rename the folder.
3. Open IntelliJ.
4. Choose the option `Create New Project`
5. Select your desired language/framework e.g. `Kotlin`, click `Next`
6. For `Project Name`, specify your desired project name. Maybe same as folder name.
7. For `Project Location`, **choose the folder that you manually renamed**.
8. Click `Finish`, IntelliJ will ask if you want to overwrite `.idea` and `.iml` files. Click `Yes` for both.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For JetBrains **v. 2019.2** (September 2019):

**To move project directory without changing it's name:**

1. Press `Alt+1` to open project structure
2. - Right click on project directory
   - Go to **File -> Refactor -> Move directory**

   OR

   - Left click on project directory
   - Press `F6`

   Specify target parent directory and hit OK.

**To rename project directory:**

1. Press `Alt+1` to open project structure
2. - Right click on project directory
   - Go to **File -> Refactor -> Rename...**

   OR

   - Left click on project directory
   - Press `Shift+F6`
3. Select **Rename directory** (actually it's already selected) and hit OK.
4. Specify new directory name.

If you need both to move project directory and to change it's name, then do the steps one after another.

After you've done renaming/moving, **close the project** and remove it from the recent projects list (it became non-functional and you won't need it anymore there).

Then hit "Open" and find the project directory at it's new location. Now you have your project directory moved!

*The last two steps should be done with a command like Edit project or something like that, where you can directly specify project directory, but as there is no such command, you need to remove project and reopen it at it's new location instead.*

Answer (score 1):

A work-arround for this, if you get an error when click "projectPackage" -> Refactor -> Move,  is to close Intellij, move the folder manually, and then in:

> C:\Users\user.name\ .IntelliJIdea2019.1\config\options

edit the file recentProjects.xml like this, with you new path, save and close, re-open jetbrains ide and it's done.

[image: configfile]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have figured this out and I will write down a step by step guide to how to rename the project directory linked to a GitHub repo.

**Situation:**

- Windows 10
- IntelliJ project is linked with a GitHub repo
- I want to rename the GitHub repo and the project directory name and keep all my work the same.

**Solution:**

1. rename the repo on GitHub, make sure pages is still working with the new name
2. rename the project from IntelliJ by (right-click on the parent directory -> refactor -> rename)
3. rename the directory from IntelliJ by (right-click on the parent directory -> open module settings -> project)
   3.1. update "project name"
   3.2. update project compiler output
4. rename the GitHub remote repo from IntelliJ by (VCS -> git -> remotes)
5. close IntelliJ
6. open System Explorer
   6.1. rename the project directory
   6.2. open "workspace.xml" and rename all occurrence of the old word (you might want to cut it in another place, update it, then paste it back)
7. open IntelliJ and select import project
8. now, everything is okay, you can use Git inside IntelliJ normally as nothing has happened!

That is it, I just made a push from IntelliJ to the renamed repo and everything works as before without any mention of the old name.

Answer (score 0):

click on your project file,which is you want to move and then push F6

Comment: Answering with shortcut key is a bad answer as everyone can change the keymap.

Answer (score 0):

```
Close IntelliJ 
Rename the folder in Explorer (Windows) / Finder
(OSX)   
Open IntelliJ Import Project from Dialog, or File -> Import
Project     
Select the folder with the new name 
further additional steps might be required if you see your module named
as  new_modulename[parent module/old module name],
then update   
settings.gradle with new name  and reimport
```