# How to delete projects in Intellij IDEA 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

I only found how to delete projects in older versions of IDEA but still don't see the button in my IDEA 14. Did the Jetbrains guys implement this feature or do I still have to delete my project folders manually in file explorer?

Comment: what happens when you press the delete key, whilst your project is highlighted ?

Comment: a popup asks me: "Remove Module 'Module Name' from the project? No files will be deleted" with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons

Comment: well there ya go, if you want to delete files from your file system, you'll have to delete files "manually"

Comment: But this feature has been proposed even in the time of version 12. Stil not implemented?

Comment: I would be surprised if this was a very popular feature request. Most people like the current behaviour

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**1.** Choose project, right click, in context menu, choose `Show in Explorer` (on Mac, select `Reveal in Finder`).
[image]

**2.** Choose menu `File \ Close Project`
[image]

**3.** In Windows Explorer, press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for permanent delete.

**4.** At IntelliJ IDEA startup windows, hover cursor on old project name (what has been deleted) press <kbd>Del</kbd> for delelte.
[image]

Comment: doesn't work on a mac, if anyone can add another answer

Comment: It in fact does work on OS X*, the option is called "Reveal in Finder".



* At least with recent IntelliJ versions, I haven't tested old releases.

Comment: Thx man, I'd never guess pressing the 'del' button... It's like: "what the ...???"

---
"Explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: A minor change to those instructions in step 4 for version 2017.2.5: just hovering the cursor over the deleted project name is insufficient; you must select it by clicking it, and then click the 'Remove from list' button in the popup dialog titled 'Reopen Project' that is displayed.

Comment: So you can't rename a project (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493379/how-to-rename-move-a-project-in-intellij-idea-12) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177495/renaming-a-project-in-intellij-idea/21180363) if you don't believe me) in a designed way and you can't delete a project in a designed way. I find it flabbergasting. Only workarounds/dirty hacks. Are you sure that just removing the deleted project from the `recent projects` list erases all its traces from the metafiles in the IntelliJ user configuration folder? I doubt it...

Comment: On Linux, the "Show in Files" option (equivalent to "Show in Explorer" in Windows) will open the location of the source folder in Files. If you want to delete all of the source files, then you can delete that folder.  If you want to delete *only* the IntelliJ project specific files, then you can just delete the `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 14):

Deleting and Recreating a project with same name is tricky. If you try to follow above suggested steps and try to create a project with same name as the one you just deleted, you will run into error like

'C:/xxxxxx/pom.xml' already exists in VFS

Here is what I found would work.

1. Remove module
2. File -> Invalidate Cache (at this point the Intelli IDEA wants to restart)
3. Close project
4. Delete the folder form system explorer.
5. Now you can create a project with same name as before.

Comment: you saved me buddy, i just migrated to intelliJ from eclipse

Comment: I followed [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206279599-How-do-you-remove-module-from-project-only-) to remove the module.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it manually in Intellij IDEA v2021.3.1, Ubuntu 20.04.

### Steps:

1. Select Project
2. File > Close Project
3. Right-click on project > Remove from Recent Projects
   [image]

4. cd ~/IdeaProjects
5. rm -fr *ProjectDir*

Comment: I removed any `.iml` file as well as the whole subdirectory `.idea` but when I reopened intellij in the project directory it complained that there is this module already. Only after I went through the procedure above (except for the `rm -rf), I could re-open and re-configure the project.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually delete from the project explorer (your local machine hard drive), then delete the project in IntelliJ when it asks to re-open recent projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my strange case, Intellij remembers forever about my project even if I delete `.iml`... Thus I did the following:

1. Close project. Delete the `.iml` file.
2. Rename my project directory (say `my_proj`) to `my_proj_backup`.
3. (Possibly not needed) Open `my_proj_backup` in Intellij and close.
4. Create an *empty* directory called `my_proj`, and open it in Intellij. Then close it.
5. Remove the `my_proj` and move `my_proj_backup` back to `my_proj`. Then open `my_proj` in Intellij.

Then it happily forgot the old `my_proj` :)