# How to fully delete project and it's metadata on IntelliJ 14 for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511348/how-to-delete-projects-in-intellij-idea-14) that I can delete a project from the recent projects list by highlighting it with the mouse, and pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd> on the keyboard.

However, I believe there is still project metadata laying around that messes things up. If I recreate a project with the same name, things are wonky. When I created the project with a new name, everything worked fine. How can I be sure to wipe out everything associated with a project when I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Project (with its modules) metadata is stored in ".idea" folder and ".iml" files.
What you need to do is to find where they are.

In the mentioned question it is suggested to use "Show In Explorer" action to find the project contents and to delete them. However, this will only work if both project sources and configuration files are in one and the same folder. For example I have my project sources in "C:\workspaces"  and project config files in "C:\Projects".

So what you need to do in addition is to make sure you've deleted the ".idea" and ".impl" from the location displayed in the recent projects list (see attachment)

[image]